# Is there a way to determine if user is singing in or up using Apple Sign In

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, apple-sign-in

When the user is signing in / up using Apple Sign In is there a way to determine whether the user already signed up once using Apple Sign In to this app or it is his first time
( If the app in **Apps Using Apple ID** list in iPhone Settings )?

[image]

I want to know whether I need to sign in the user in the server side or continue to sign up flow after

> func authorizationController(controller: ASAuthorizationController, didCompleteWithAuthorization authorization: ASAuthorization)

is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check for existing login details on app launch using the app delegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let appleIDProvider = ASAuthorizationAppleIDProvider()
    appleIDProvider.getCredentialState(forUserID: KeychainItem.currentUserIdentifier) { (credentialState, error) in
        switch credentialState {
        case .authorized:
            break // The Apple ID credential is valid.
        case .revoked, .notFound:
            // The Apple ID credential is either revoked or was not found, so show the sign-in UI.
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.window?.rootViewController?.showLoginViewController()
            }
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple